# Can I automatically strip out vcf attachments in Outlook 2011?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, attachments, microsoft-outlook-2011

I'm corresponding a lot with someone whose sig includes a virtual business card file (.vcf), which means I have lots and lots of emails with an attachment I don't care about. Each one's only 8.3KB, but that adds up.

I figure it's a long shot, but is there any way I can tell Outlook 2011 for Mac to remove/block .vcf attachments from incoming emails?

Answer (score 0):

That is not native behavior for Outlook. There aren't even any options for rules to do this. Many add-ins for attachment handling exist, but I do not know which ones will do what you seek. Below is an alternative.

In the blog article, [Delete vcf Attachment from Incoming Emails](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2009/07/10/delete-vcf-attachment-from-incoming-emails/), it explains how to use VBA to check for and remove `.vcf` attachments. The below code can be placed in the `ThisOutlookSession` module. It runs when emails are received to remove attachments with `.vcf` extensions.

Keep in mind, it removes them all. Not just specific ones.

```
Private Sub Application_NewMail()

    Dim mi As MailItem
    Dim att As Attachment

    For Each mi In Me.GetNamespace(“MAPI”).GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
        If mi.Unread Then
            If mi.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
                For Each att In mi.Attachments
                    If Right$(att.FileName, 4) = “.vcf” Then
                        att.Delete
                        mi.Save
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next att
            End If
        End If
    Next mi


End Sub
```

I make no claim to how this will work because I do not know what your level of expertise is and I have not tested this. Either way, it should get you headed in the right direction.